# Searching a string in a different position in a MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I got this problem when searching a string inside mySql.

Scenario : I want to do a smart search which is, the saved data in my database is this (refer to image)

[image]

I'm using  `SELECT * from table where name like '%snow%'` this code is working but when I put `like '%jon snow%'` it is not displaying the result. what should be the problem or solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried something like this:
SELECT * from table where name like '%Snow%' and name like '%Jon%'

Comment: you should not store multiple values in single column. It even violates the `normalization rules`. Instead you should make a separate column for the last/2nd name etc

Comment: @UsmanRana I both agree and disagree with the statement for the example: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @AustinFrench, btw this screenshot is from a result of view that's why it was all collected in a single field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as how you aren't looking for a string like "Jon Snow" this wouldn't work.

You'll want either

```
SELECT * from table where name like '%snow%'and name like '%jon%'
```

or

```
SELECT * from table where name like '%snow%' or name like '%jon%'
```

both would work for example, but if you want ONLY rows with both *jon* and *snow* I'd use the first.

Comment: little typo -> SELECT * from table where name like '%snow%' or name like '%jon%'

Comment: @Allan thanks, amazing I got the name right 75% of the time.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I just tried it and its working,.